# Problem with the mdadm Raid 5 array on Linux

Tags: linux, raspberry-pi, raid, mdadm, raid5

I have a big problem here:

Until a week ago everything worked perfectly with my mdadm array. I then let it shut down for a week and only now started it up again. Shortly afterwards, I noticed a first problem: the LED was not lit on one of my 3 500GB hard drives. So far, not bad. Then I went in via SSH and then found out: my raid was broken.

```
    pi@raspberrypi:~ $ sudo mdadm --detail /dev/md0
/dev/md0:
           Version : 1.2
     Creation Time : Sat May  2 18:51:06 2020
        Raid Level : raid5
     Used Dev Size : 488251904 (465.63 GiB 499.97 GB)
      Raid Devices : 3
     Total Devices : 1
       Persistence : Superblock is persistent

       Update Time : Fri May 21 13:46:39 2021
             State : active, FAILED, Not Started
    Active Devices : 1
   Working Devices : 1
    Failed Devices : 0
     Spare Devices : 0

            Layout : left-symmetric
        Chunk Size : 64K

Consistency Policy : unknown

              Name : raspberrypi:0  (local to host raspberrypi)
              UUID : 23f436a0:c3f13920:01784b25:b4581c36
            Events : 48112

    Number   Major   Minor   RaidDevice State
       -       0        0        0      removed
       -       0        0        1      removed
       -       0        0        2      removed

       -       8       33        1      sync   /dev/sdc1
pi@raspberrypi:~ $ cat /proc/mdstat
Personalities : [raid6] [raid5] [raid4]
md0 : inactive sdc1[4]
      488254584 blocks super 1.2

unused devices: <none>
pi@raspberrypi:~ $ lsblk
NAME        MAJ:MIN RM   SIZE RO TYPE MOUNTPOINT
sda           8:0    0 465,8G  0 disk
└─sda1        8:1    0 465,8G  0 part
sdb           8:16   0 465,8G  0 disk
└─sdb1        8:17   0 465,8G  0 part
sdc           8:32   0 465,8G  0 disk
└─sdc1        8:33   0 465,8G  0 part
mmcblk0     179:0    0  14,9G  0 disk
├─mmcblk0p1 179:1    0   256M  0 part /boot
└─mmcblk0p2 179:2    0  14,6G  0 part /
```

This should not be like that. / dev / sda, / dev / sdb and / dev / sdc should be yours in the array. I thought about it and it looks like 2 hard drives have failed at the same time (in retrospect I think the LED is always off when there is no activity) and now the array cannot be rebuilt. If I reboot with only 2 hard drives, this is what comes out:

```
    pi@raspberrypi:~ $ sudo mdadm --detail /dev/md0
/dev/md0:
           Version : 1.2
        Raid Level : raid0
     Total Devices : 2
       Persistence : Superblock is persistent

             State : inactive
   Working Devices : 2

              Name : raspberrypi:0  (local to host raspberrypi)
              UUID : 23f436a0:c3f13920:01784b25:b4581c36
            Events : 48112

    Number   Major   Minor   RaidDevice

       -       8       17        -        /dev/sdb1
       -       8        1        -        /dev/sda1
pi@raspberrypi:~ $ cat /proc/mdstat
Personalities :
md0 : inactive sdb1[4](S) sda1[0](S)
      976509169 blocks super 1.2

unused devices: <none>
pi@raspberrypi:~ $ lsblk
NAME        MAJ:MIN RM   SIZE RO TYPE MOUNTPOINT
sda           8:0    0 465,8G  0 disk
└─sda1        8:1    0 465,8G  0 part
sdb           8:16   0 465,8G  0 disk
└─sdb1        8:17   0 465,8G  0 part
mmcblk0     179:0    0  14,9G  0 disk
├─mmcblk0p1 179:1    0   256M  0 part /boot
└─mmcblk0p2 179:2    0  14,6G  0 part /
```

I rebooted the Pi and now this is coming out and I'm even more confused (it should be a Raid 5 array)

```
pi@raspberrypi:~ $ lsblk
NAME        MAJ:MIN RM   SIZE RO TYPE MOUNTPOINT
sda           8:0    0 465,8G  0 disk
└─sda1        8:1    0 465,8G  0 part
sdb           8:16   0 465,8G  0 disk
└─sdb1        8:17   0 465,8G  0 part
sdc           8:32   0 465,8G  0 disk
└─sdc1        8:33   0 465,8G  0 part
mmcblk0     179:0    0  14,9G  0 disk
├─mmcblk0p1 179:1    0   256M  0 part /boot
└─mmcblk0p2 179:2    0  14,6G  0 part /
pi@raspberrypi:~ $ cat /proc/mdstat
Personalities :
md0 : inactive sda1[0](S) sdc1[4](S) sdb1[3](S)
      1464762761 blocks super 1.2

unused devices: <none>
pi@raspberrypi:~ $ sudo mdadm --detail /dev/md0
/dev/md0:
           Version : 1.2
        Raid Level : raid0
     Total Devices : 3
       Persistence : Superblock is persistent

             State : inactive
   Working Devices : 3

              Name : raspberrypi:0  (local to host raspberrypi)
              UUID : 23f436a0:c3f13920:01784b25:b4581c36
            Events : 48112

    Number   Major   Minor   RaidDevice

       -       8       33        -        /dev/sdc1
       -       8       17        -        /dev/sdb1
       -       8        1        -        /dev/sda1
```

I hope that someone will know how to get the array back together, since the data on all hard drives should still be there.

I do have a backup, but some data on the Raid isn't present on my backup.

Kind regards,
Elytronn

Comment: mdadm --examine for all drives?